# Ultra Numeric Editor is setting default up to 2 decimal places only

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics

How to use  `UltraNumericEditor.MaskInput` to enter input up to 10 or more decimal places?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the *more decimal places* because the MaskInput property requires the exact number of decimals that you want to type.

So, if you want to get till a maximum of 10 decimals you could write

```
numEditor.NumericType = NumericType.Decimal
numEditor.MaskInput = "{LOC}n.nnnnnnnnnn"
```

where the `{LOC}` prefix allows to type the localized symbol for decimal point.
If you need a dynamic number of decimals then you could build at runtime this mask or use the equivalent syntax

```
numEditor.MaskInput = "{LOC}{double:1.10:c}"
```

In any case you need to know in advance how many digits are required for the integer and fractional part.

You could find a lot of examples about MaskInput format at this link on the Infragistics web site

[MaskInput property](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2011.2/CLR2.0/html/Infragistics2.Win.UltraWinGrid.v11.2~Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridColumn~MaskInput.html)